# Get JSON data from SSH server with url in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ssh

---

I am trying to get all the data from my NOSQL Database which is on an SSH server and asign it to the variable  text. I have a code snipped which is not working and i have no idear what i have to change because i am new to this. Thank you.

```
var text;

    //Request senden
    try {
        text = new XMLHttpRequest();
        text
                .open(
                        'URL is placed here'); //  
        asyncRequest.send(null);
    } catch (exception) {
        alert("Request to Database failed!!");
    }
```

Comment: First thing to notice is that the XMLHttpRequest object has a name of `text` and you are using a name of `asyncRequest` to send. There are many frameworks that make this easier. JQuery is one of them. if you want to use vanilla JS then check out this link on how the XMLHttpRequest works: http://www.w3schools.com/xml/dom_http.asp

Comment: Is SSH same as HTTP?

Comment: @SalmanA I think it is the same then HTTP. Do you maybe have a code snipped ?  Do you think it works because my request returns JSON data

Answer (score -1):

how about using

```
$.get('url',null/object,function(data){
    ...get result into data here    
});
```

Much easier to use with jQuery here....is [how to](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/)